# Formula for choosing $x$ elements from a set containing $n$ elements, with repetition allowed

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

I've been searching around for a formula for the number of cmbinations for choosing $x$ elements from a set containing $n$ elements. For instance, for the set $(1,2,3)$ we have $10$ different ways of choosing $3$ elements: $(1,2,2)$,$(1,3,3)$,$(1,1,2)$,$(1,1,3)$....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $n$ types of elements, from which you take $k$. If you call $u_i$ the number of elements of type $i$, this is:

$\begin{align}
  u_1 + u_2 + \dotsb + u_n = k
\end{align}$

Now use the following idea, called [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)): Mark each element by a star $*$, separate types by bars $\mid$. This gives a string of $n - 1$ bars and $k$ stars, for $n + k - 1$ symbols in all, of which $n - 1$ are bars, giving

$\begin{align}
  \binom{n + k - 1}{n - 1}
\end{align}$

possibilities.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Sorry, my mistake.